# get only the path excluding the file name and add it with double quote

Tags: lua

I want to get only the path excluding the file name and use it inside popen.

I want to only take "/this/is a/path/" from "/this/is a/path/my file.mp4". Then add it to `kdialog --getsavefilename` so that the command looks like"

```
kdialog --getsavefilename "/this/is a/path/"
```

The following code is not working.

```
foo = "/this/is a/path/my file.mp4"
bar = foo:gsub("(.*)\/.*$","%1")
local handle = io.popen("kdialog --getsavefilename " .. bar)
local file_path = handle:read("*a")
handle:close()
```

What is the fix here?

Comment: You didn't quote `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
foo = "/this/is a/path/my file.gif"
bar = foo:gsub("(.*)/.*$","%1")
local kdialogcommand = string.format("kdialog --getsavefilename %q '*.gif' | tr -d '\n'", bar)
local handle = io.popen(kdialogcommand)
local file_path = handle:read("*a")
handle:close()
```